# Flask SQLAlchemy: filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following lines in my python api which deletes a function created by user from postgres db upon request.

```
@func_app.route("/delete", methods=["POST"])

def delete_func():
    try:
         JSON = request.get_json()

         user_func = function_table.query.filter_by( 
         created_by=token_payload["email"], functionid=JSON["funcId"]
         ).all()
         functionid=JSON["funcId"]
         func_detail = function_table.query.filter_by(functionid).first()


         user = users_table.query.filter_by(email=token_payload["username"]).first()

         if len(user_func) == 0:
             log_metric(g.request_id + " " + "No functions found")
             return make_response(
               jsonify("User does not have any functions. Please try again later."),
              204,
               )
        else:
            function_table.query.filter_by(functionid).delete()
            db.session.commit()


   except Exception as err:
        db.session.rollback()
        log_metric(g.request_id + " " + str(err))
        return make_response(
            jsonify(
                "Unable to process your request at the moment. Please try again later."
             ),
           400,
            )
    finally:
         db.session.close()
```

I have used **filter_by** similarly before but there I didn't find any issue. Can anyone help me figure out what went wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: filter_by() is at 4 places. Please cut out the unnecessary parts and update the question with the line which has the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the column name with the value in filter_by, it take `**kwargs` arguments not `*args` type of input.

you need to change

```
func_detail = function_table.query.filter_by(functionid).first()
```

to

```
func_detail = function_table.query.filter_by(id = functionid).first()
```

considering `id` is column name.

For more information, see the [sqlalchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by).

Comment: Thanks that worked!! Actually functionid itself is the columname so I assigned it before and passed it in filter_by, that was causing the issue